# Error tx_bad_seq, is it just about the sequence number?

Tags: accounts, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory, sequence-number, error

I have a problem broadcasting a transaction for stellar.

It ends and gives me the error `tx_bad_seq`. The thing is I have checked and rechecked the account sequence number multiple times. I feed in the sequence number for the account `GCLT45QVPRNNVOOW6CU2WAO4OPEV5OK45YZBMD2EXRNX3KLQPBFTPHDD` as `126165149651304448`. It then increments the sequence number to `126165149651304449` and then signs the transaction. The signing goes as smoothly as it has a 1000 times before. In fact, to check if I was signing with the right sequence number I put in `126165149651304449` instead of `126165149651304448` and tried submitting that transaction. I still get the same error code.

The thing is I cannot understand what exactly is the problem. Discussions online suggest that it is a problem with the sequence number, but I think this has something more to it. I have checked the same sequence number on https://laboratory.stellar.org/#explorer?resource=accounts&endpoint=single&network=public and I still am getting the same error. Could it be the way I initialized the account?

https://stellarchain.io/address/GCLT45QVPRNNVOOW6CU2WAO4OPEV5OK45YZBMD2EXRNX3KLQPBFTPHDD

I initialized it with 20 XLM instead of 1 XLM. But I am not sure that this should create a problem like this. And if it is a problem, how to solve it?

Comment: After experience, it can happen to you if you are using a different signing key. If you believe you are using the right signing key, try to use that exact same key to generate the from address.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence number for a new transaction must be the current sequence number +1. You can look up the current sequence number at: https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/[ACCOUNT_ID]

Given the fact you asked this question at `2020-04-28 06:42:22Z`, the last (and for now only new) transaction on your account was at `2020-04-28T08:59:18Z` and the current sequence number is indeed `126165149651304449`, I guess you figured it out in meantime and you had somehow tried a different number than that before.